# Вернуть дочерний элемент WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Нужно вернуть дочерний элемент. Есть какой то Panel например, в нем есть несколько PictureBox, label и бог знает что еще. Мне нужно вытащить PictureBox по его Name. Может есть какой-то универсальный метод, который это реализует, потому что я нашел только Controls, который возвращает список всех дочерних элементов. Вот как я накостылил конкретно для своей задачи, но эта штука не универсальна, хотелось бы иметь метод для этих целей:

```
var playPause_controls = panels[currentTrack.track].Controls;//Получаю всех дочек из Panel
foreach(var playPause in playPause_controls) {
    if (playPause is PictureBox) {//Если тип PictureBox
        var pp = (PictureBox)playPause;//Костыль, т.к. не знаю как еще узнать Name
        if(Regex.IsMatch(pp.Name, "PlayPause")) {//Если имя совпадает
            pp.Image = Properties.Resources.play_button;//Действия...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: нет, то что вы спрашиваете, можно получить только перебором с последующим анализом. Другой вопрос, зачем вы хотите это сделать?Если чуть подробнее опишите более общую задачу - скорее всего, есть решение, где перебор дочерних элементов не потребуется.

Comment: У меня есть список Panel, в каждом этом Panel есть несколько PictureBox, я при нажатии на Panel должен получить PictureBox с конкретным именем. Можно конечно составить еще один список для PictureBox, но я думаю это излишне, ответ ниже мне подошел.

Comment: Ну не хотите - не надо,я не настаиваю.

Comment: Нет, я ищу оптимальное решение, если есть еще лучше и быстрее, то скажите, я буду благодарен и все, кто ищут ответ на этот вопрос, тоже.

Comment: Тогда, все таки, опишите задачу подробнее, зачем вам все эти списки контролов и прямой доступ к ним. Лучше отдельным вопросом, чтобы принятый ответ остался актуальным. Скорее всего задача решается путем создания кастомных контролов и маршрутизацией событий, но нужны подробности от вас =)

Comment: Если говорить конкретно, то у меня есть список аудиодорожек(Panel), у каждой аудиодорожки есть кнопка Play, при нажатии на нее она меняется на Pause и если уже играл какой-то трек, то у играющего трека заменить Pause на Play (это все картинки). Как я мыслил, у меня есть List из этих Panel и переменная в которой храню трек, который сейчас играет, например играет 3й трек, тогда при нажатии на второй я получаю картинку pause 3го и заменяю её на play. Вот это и есть сама задача. Почему я не сделал сразу List из Play? Потому что мне нужен доступ ко всем остальным контролам тоже, из Panel это легче.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64225/discussion-between-rdorn-and-max).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если вам надо вытянуть только 1 элемент в `Panel`, зная его имя, то можно так:

```
var picture = panel1.Controls.Find("pictureBox1", true).FirstOrDefault();
```

По порядку:

- `panel1` - наш элемент `Panel`.
- `.Controls` - Список всех дочерних элементов.
- `.Find` - Ищем в данном списке по имени.
- `.FirstOrDefault()` - первый найденный элемент.
- Так же можно явно задать тип получаемого объекта, указав в начале строки `(PictureBox)` (это если надо конечно).